# How to modify the name of a file?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's suppose that this is the name of my numpy file:

```
 File1.npy
 File2.npy
```

I need to modify the name of the file by adding an important information:

```
File1_SV1. npy 
File2_SV2
```

I try by using this line of code:

```
path ='C:\\Users\\mky\\Folder'
Files= os.listdir(path)
for File in Files:
      SV= # I must calculate the SV
      os.rename(os.path.join(path,File), os.path.join(path, File+SV))
```

It gives me this error:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(path,File), os.path.join(path, File+SV))
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Comment: convert `SV` to a string

Comment: Probably `SV` is an int and not string. You can cast it to string by wrapping it with `str()` literal. i.e. `str(SV)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
f1 = File.replace('.npy',"")
os.rename(os.path.join(path,File), os.path.join(path, f1+str(SV)+".npy"))
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.